# Finding Avarage from array of JSON objects asynchronously

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, asynchronous

I have the following JSON and I wan to find avarage of pressure grouped by `deviceId`:

```
[
    {
        "deviceId": 121,
        "Pressure": 120
    },
    {
        "deviceId": 121,
        "Pressure": 80
    },
    {
        "deviceId": 130,
        "Pressure": 20
    },
    {
        "deviceId": 130,
        "Pressure": 25
    },
    {
        "deviceId": 130,
        "Pressure": 75
    }
]
```

I want to get

```
[
    {
        "deviceId" : 121,
        "avg-Pressure": 100
    },
    {
        "deviceId": 130,
        "avg-Pressure": 40
    }
]
```

How can I do this by using native methods and can I do it asynchronously?

Comment: Hi! When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info in it. There was also a toolbar full of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area showing what your post would look like when posted, located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it). Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: (I've fixed the formatting for you.)

Comment: And the answer to your question is yes, of course you can do it (once you parse the JSON into an object). It's just simple maths. Get the values you need, and average them. What have you researched or tried? It shouldn't be too hard to make an attempt. Also it's not clear why being asynchronous would be important but I guess in theory you could wrap your code in a Promise, but doesn't necessarily make it fully asynchronous. Why do you (think you) need that?

Comment: @ADyson - Indeed, wrapping it in a Promise definitely **doesn't** make it asynchronous. :-) (The promise executor runs synchronously.) You could put it in a `then` handler, but that just makes it synchronous *later*. To make it truly asynchronous, you'd have to offload it to a web worker thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to group your data on `deviceId` along with `count` and `totalPressure`. Then using `array#map` calculate the average pressure for each `deviceId`.

```js
const data = [ { "deviceId": 121, "Pressure": 120 }, { "deviceId": 121, "Pressure": 80 }, { "deviceId": 130, "Pressure": 20 }, { "deviceId": 130, "Pressure": 25 }, { "deviceId": 130, "Pressure": 75 } ],
      result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, {deviceId, Pressure}) => {
        r[deviceId] = r[deviceId] || {deviceId, totalPressure : 0, count : 0};
        r[deviceId].totalPressure += Pressure;
        r[deviceId].count += 1;
        return r;
      }, {}))
      .map(({deviceId, totalPressure, count}) => ({deviceId, 'avg-Pressure' : totalPressure/count}));
      
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce your array to an object where the key is the deviceId and the value is an object with deviceId and an array of Pressure values:

```
data.reduce(
  (result,{deviceId,Pressure})=>{
    result[deviceId] = result[deviceId] || {deviceId,Pressure:[]};
    result[deviceId].Pressure.push(Pressure);
    return result;    
  },
  {}
)
```

Then use `Object.values` to turn that into an array again.

Then map the array to an array of objects where `Pressure` is one value so reduce the Pressure values of each object to the sum of all pressures divided by the length of the Pressures array

```
valuesWithArrayOfPressure.map(
  ({deviceId,Pressure})=>({
    deviceId,
    Pressure:Pressure.reduce((all,item)=>all+item,0)
  })
)
```

Complete code:

```js
var data = [
    {
        "deviceId": 121,
        "Pressure": 120
    },
    {
        "deviceId": 121,
        "Pressure": 80
    },
    {
        "deviceId": 130,
        "Pressure": 20
    },
    {
        "deviceId": 130,
        "Pressure": 25
    },
    {
        "deviceId": 130,
        "Pressure": 75
    }
];

const valuesWithArrayOfPressure = data.reduce(
  (result, { deviceId, Pressure }) => {
    result[deviceId] = result[deviceId] || {
      deviceId,
      Pressure: [],
    };
    result[deviceId].Pressure.push(Pressure);
    return result;
  },
  {},
);
console.log(
  'object where Pressure is grouped',
  valuesWithArrayOfPressure,
);

console.log(
  'use values and map to get average Pressure values',
  Object.values(valuesWithArrayOfPressure).map(
    ({ deviceId, Pressure }) => ({
      deviceId,
      Pressure: Pressure.reduce(
        (all, item) => all + item,
        0,
      ),
    }),
  ),
);
```

Comment: In my code as it is running in node server i need this to be made asynchronous .

Comment: @AmjathKhan Not sure what you mean by `made asynchrounous`.

Comment: @AmjathKhan why do you need it to be asynchronous? It will take a matter of milliseconds to execute.

Comment: @ADyson i have records of size 2400000 records . And multiple other queries will be coming in

Comment: @ADyson actually i am doing this for cosmos DB , where it uses native javascript api and simultaneously others will making request call to it.

Answer (score 1):

I store the JSON values in `arr` object.

Also declared the `newArray` to store the results;

I invoked `findAvaragePressure` with the `arr` and `newArray` to grab the desired results.

```
// store the result here
let newArray = [];
const arr = [
    {
        "deviceId": 121,
        "Pressure": 120
    },
    {
        "deviceId": 121,
        "Pressure": 80
    },
    {
        "deviceId": 130,
        "Pressure": 20
    },
    {
        "deviceId": 130,
        "Pressure": 25
    },
    {
        "deviceId": 130,
        "Pressure": 75
    }
];

// check if the object is already token in the new array
const isAvailable = (deviceId, arr) => {
    for (let index=0; index<arr.length; index++) {
        if (arr[index].deviceId == deviceId) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// for a device id, find the average pressure
const getAvarageValue = (deviceId, arr) => {
    let sum = 0;
    let count = 0;
    for (let index=0; index<arr.length; index++) {
        if (arr[index].deviceId == deviceId) {
            sum += arr[index].Pressure;
            count ++;
        }
    }
    return sum/count;
};

// put the existing array object and new resultent array
const findAvaragePressure = (arr, newArray) => {
    for (let index=0; index<arr.length; index++) {
        if (!isAvailable(arr[index].deviceId, newArray)) {
            const avg_Pressure = getAvarageValue(arr[index].deviceId, arr);
            newArray.push({
                deviceId: arr[index].deviceId,
                avg_Pressure: avg_Pressure
            });
        }
    };
    return newArray
};

const result = findAvaragePressure(arr, newArray);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answers, you could try grouping by `deviceId`, and calculating the averages from those groups:

```js
const json = [{
  "deviceId": 121,
  "Pressure": 120
}, {
  "deviceId": 121,
  "Pressure": 80
}, {
  "deviceId": 130,
  "Pressure": 20
}, {
  "deviceId": 130,
  "Pressure": 25
}, {
  "deviceId": 130,
  "Pressure": 75
}]

const deviceGroups = {};
for (const key in json) {
  deviceId = json[key].deviceId;

  if (!deviceGroups[deviceId]) {
    deviceGroups[deviceId] = []
  }

  deviceGroups[deviceId].push(json[key])
}

result = [];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(deviceGroups)) {
  const jsonObject = {
    "deviceId": key
  };

  let sum = 0;
  for (const array in deviceGroups[key]) {
    sum += deviceGroups[key][array].Pressure;
  }

  jsonObject["avg-Pressure"] = sum / deviceGroups[key].length;
  result.push(jsonObject);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: How can we make this asynchronous ?